# How can I combine Kinect data with Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, visual-studio-2015, kinect

I'm currently trying to create a GUI that will display Kinect data as well as a couple control features (buttons, etc.) and a graph. The control features and the graph is simple enough however I'm a bit stuck on how to continue on with the Kinect.

I've looked at numerous examples for MSVS and Kinect Studio but I can't quite figure out how to import the Kinect data to my Qt script. Also, I need it so that the Qt data can be recorded then replayed when a button is pressed.

How should I go about this? My hope is some how I can extract the Kinect data in its raw (x,y,z) format then reconstruct the data using `openGL`? I've seen references of `OpenNI` as well as `OpenCV` but I'm unfamiliar with either. I'm pretty familar with Qt but have virtually no experience with Kinect development.

I'm currently using Qt5 Creator, MSVS2015, and Kinect SDK2.